# Factoring $x$ out of the denominator of a limit

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Given the limit $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\ln (x^2 +1)}{x}$ how do you compute it without using l'Hopital's rule so that the indeterminancy goes away?

Answer (score 1):

Simply you have$$\frac{1}{1+x}=1-x+x^2-....\implies
\\\frac{1}{1+x^2}=1-x^2+x^4-....\implies
\\\frac{2x}{1+x^2}=2(x-x^3+x^5-....)\implies
\\\ln{(1+x^2)}=2(\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\frac{x^6}{6}-....)\implies
\\\frac{\ln{(1+x^2)}}{x}=2(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^3}{4}+\frac{x^5}{6}-....)$$
Now it is clear that the limit is zero.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\ln(1+y)}y=1$$

Answer (score 0):

I used the fundamental limit: $\displaystyle \lim_{v\rightarrow 0}(1+v)^{\frac{1}{v}}=e$.

Indeed,
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln (x^2+1)}{x} =\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\ln (1+x^2)^{\frac{1}{x}}=\ln \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(1+x^2)^{\frac{1}{x^2}\frac{x^2}{x}}=\ln e^{\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x}=\ln e^0=\ln 1 =0.$$